# make more simple jquery source code

Tags: jquery

i have made jquery source which is... 
when mouse hover on the sub menu, add class(on) on main menu....

so the code is like this on below......

```
$('#gnbMenu .subM1').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m1').toggleClass('on');
    });
    $('#gnbMenu .subM2').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m2').toggleClass('on');
    });
    $('#gnbMenu .subM3').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m3').toggleClass('on');
    });
    $('#gnbMenu .subM4').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m4').toggleClass('on');
    });
    $('#gnbMenu .subM5').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m5').toggleClass('on');
    });
    $('#gnbMenu .subM6').hover(function() {
      $('#gnbMenu .m6').toggleClass('on');
    });
```

I think this script is little ugly, so is there any way to make more simple and clean?

Comment: can you share the relevant html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign value to sub menu like 1,2,3. Then make a common class for all submenu (ex: subM)

then change the code like below

```
 $('#gnbMenu .subM').hover(function() {
  $('#gnbMenu .m'+$(this).val()).toggleClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS instead.

```
#gnbMenu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

You should never use the "hover" javascript event because it doesn't work well on touch screen browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap this logic in a function and call it as one liners

```
function MyFunction(hoverSelector,toggleSelector){
 $(hoverSelector).hover(function() {
      $(toggleSelector).toggleClass('on');
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#gnbMenu [class*="subM"]').hover(function(){
    $('#gnbMenu .m' + this.className.match(/subM(\d+)/)[1]).toggleClass('on');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them all a single class (say `subMGeneral`).

Add a `data-` attribute for second class name.

e.g. `<span class='subM1 subMGeneral' data-class='m1'>`

Then you can turn it all into

```
$('#gnbMenu .subMGeneral').hover(function() {
  $('#gnbMenu .' + $(this).data('class')).toggleClass('on');
});
```

Seeing the HTML might give more insight.